# Is the scalar propagator an even function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, propagator

The scalar propagator for the Klein-Gordon Lagrangian is given by:

$$D(x-y)=\int \frac{d^{4} k}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \frac{e^{i k(x-y)}}{k^{2}-m^{2}+i \varepsilon}$$

I need to know if it is an even function, i.e.:

$$D(x-y) = D(-(x-y)) = \int \frac{d^{4} k}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \frac{e^{i k(x-y)}}{k^{2}-m^{2}+i \varepsilon}\tag{1}$$

Since $k^2=k_0^2-\vec{k}^2$ and $k_0^2$ and $\vec{k}^2$ are both positive.

Also

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d^4k e^{ik(x-y)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d^4k e^{-ik(x-y)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d^4k e^{ik(y-x)}$$

So can we conclude that equation 1 is indeed true?

edit: rephrased the question hope it makes sense now

Comment: Do you mean $D(x-y) = D(y-x)$ ?

Comment: I think you mean, when asking if it is even, if $D(x-y) = D(y-x)$ since what you've written cancels to $D(x-y)=D(x-y)$ which is obviously true.

Comment: Yes, it is true that $D(x-y) = D(-(y-x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $D(x) = D(-x)$ follows immediately from the fact that the both the integrand and the integration measure are invariant under Lorentz transformations, and recalling that $x \to -x$ (parity transformation) is indeed a Lorentz transformation.

Alternatively, it's not difficult to prove it explicitly.
\begin{align}
D(-x) &= \int_{R^4}\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{ik\cdot (-x)}}{k^2-m^2+i\varepsilon} \\
&= \int_{R^4}\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{i(-k)\cdot x}}{k^2-m^2+i\varepsilon}.
\end{align}
Now make the substitution $k' = -k$. Since $|\det(\partial k'/\partial k)|=|-1|=1$ and under this substitution $R^4$ gets mapped into itself, we have, by [substitution for multiple variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables),
\begin{align}
\phantom{D(-x)} &= \int_{R^4}\frac{d^4k'}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{ik'\cdot x}}{(-k')^2-m^2+i\varepsilon} \\
&= \int_{R^4}\frac{d^4k'}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{ik'\cdot x}}{k'^2-m^2+i\varepsilon} \\
&= D(x)
\end{align}
(since $k'$ is just a dummy variable; we also used the fact that $(-k)^2 = k^2$).

Hope that this doesn't get through as too pedantic, and possibly clarifies! Cheers